# What is the best similarity/distance formula to use when comparing ordered rankings?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

So in a few days I will have the rankings of 30 songs from 15 people compiled into a 30x15 matrix.  Each column will contain the numbers 1-30 in some order, and I want to use a distance formula to figure out how similar any two given columns are (e.g. with the euclidean distance, smaller:more similar).  Is there some type of distance/similarity formula (like Manhattan Chebysnev) that would give a most reliable or most accurate similarity for a ranking?

Comment: "most reliable" or "most accurate" in what sense?

Comment: @Henry in the sense that it best represents how similar the two are?  I'm not overly familiar with stats so i don't quite know, that's why I'm asking the question

Comment: Statistics does not work that way.  You first have to say what matters to you.  For example do you care most about top ranks? Perhaps the rankers do not really bother with care ranking songs they do not like, or perhaps they do.

Comment: @Henry they do, the point of this is to sort them into groups of 4 (by which 4 groups have the most similar tastes in music)